# Shader with threejs material not working in aframe

Tags: three.js, shader, aframe

I am trying to add waves through a custom shader for an entity created inside a component but the scene disappears as soon as the shader is added. If I remove the shader, the entity is displayed as a static entity.

Console does not throw any error so I am not sure what is going wrong

Here is a codepen: [codepen](https://codepen.io/nirajupadhyay11/pen/dgNBRJ?editors=1000)

If you remove the material property, the entity will get displayed.

```
    <script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent('waves', {
  init: function() {
    var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "https://cinemont.com/tutorials/zelda/water.png" );
    texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.repeat.set(5, 5);
  this.geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 4000, 2000, 128, 64 ); 
  this.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
   map:texture,
   color: 0xffffff,
   opacity: 1,
   blending: THREE.NoBlending,
   side: THREE.DoubleSide,
   transparent: false,
   depthTest: false,
   wireframe: false 
  });
    var plane = new THREE.Mesh(this.geometry, this.material);
    plane.position.set(0, -400, -300);
    plane.rotation.set(Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    var el = this.el;
    el.setObject3D('mesh', plane);
  }
});
</script>
<script>
AFRAME.registerShader('makewaves', {
  schema: {
    color: {type: 'color', is: 'uniform', default: '#0051da'},
    timeMsec: {type: 'time', is: 'uniform'}
  },

  vertexShader: `
#define SCALE 10.0

varying vec2 vUv;

uniform float timeMsec;  

float calculateSurface(float x, float z) {
    float uTime = timeMsec / 1000.0;
    float y = 0.0;
    y += (sin(x * 1.0 / SCALE + uTime * 1.0) + sin(x * 2.3 / SCALE + uTime * 1.5) + sin(x * 3.3 / SCALE + uTime * 0.4)) / 3.0;
    y += (sin(z * 0.2 / SCALE + uTime * 1.8) + sin(z * 1.8 / SCALE + uTime * 1.8) + sin(z * 2.8 / SCALE + uTime * 0.8)) / 3.0;
    return y;
}

void main() {
    float uTime = timeMsec / 1000.0;
    vUv = uv;
    vec3 pos = position;    
    float strength = 1.0;
    pos.y += strength * calculateSurface(pos.x, pos.z);
    pos.y -= strength * calculateSurface(0.0, 0.0);
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(pos, 1.0);
}  
`,
  fragmentShader: `
varying vec2 vUv;

uniform sampler2D uMap;

uniform vec3 color;

uniform float timeMsec; 

void main() {
    float uTime = timeMsec / 1000.0;     
    vec2 uv = vUv * 10.0 + vec2(uTime * -0.05);

    uv.y += 0.01 * (sin(uv.x * 3.5 + uTime * 0.35) + sin(uv.x * 4.8 + uTime * 1.05) + sin(uv.x * 7.3 + uTime * 0.45)) / 3.0;
    uv.x += 0.12 * (sin(uv.y * 4.0 + uTime * 0.5) + sin(uv.y * 6.8 + uTime * 0.75) + sin(uv.y * 11.3 + uTime * 0.2)) / 3.0;
    uv.y += 0.12 * (sin(uv.x * 4.2 + uTime * 0.64) + sin(uv.x * 6.3 + uTime * 1.65) + sin(uv.x * 8.2 + uTime * 0.45)) / 3.0;

    vec4 tex1 = texture2D(uMap, uv * 1.0);
    vec4 tex2 = texture2D(uMap, uv * 1.0 + vec2(0.2));

    vec3 blue = color;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(blue + vec3(tex1.a * 0.9 - tex2.a * 0.02), 1.0);

}`
});
</script>
<a-scene>
        <a-camera postion="0 1.2 0"></a-camera>     
  <a-entity material="shader:makewaves;" 
            waves></a-entity>
  <a-entity light="type: directional; color: #ffffff; intensity: 2.8; castShadow:true;" position="0 2 -10"></a-entity>
  <a-light type="point" color="blue" position="0 5 0"></a-light>
    <a-light type="directional" color="blue" intensity="1.8" position="0 5 0"></a-light> 
</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that your shader in the applied material does not provide the map uniform / texture value.

On the other hand you try to create the material twice:

1) First you create the material with the `a-frame`s `material` component
2) Then you create a new geometry + a new material (with an incorrect THREE material type) within the `waves` component.
You need to either let `a-frame` take care of most of this, or create the mesh (geometry + material) entirely in THREE.js.

**AFRAME**
Not so much to be added here. Your shader does not expose any uniform for the texture, so inside the `registerShader` you need to add it to the schema:

```
AFRAME.registerShader('makewaves', {
  schema: {
     ......,
    uMap: {
      type: 'map',
      is: 'uniform'
    }
  }, .....
```

and use your shader like this:

```
<a-plane postion="1 1.2 2" width="5" height="5" rotation="-90 0 90" material="shader:makewaves; 
uMap: https://cinemont.com/tutorials/zelda/water.png;"></a-plane>
```

Then `a-frame` will create a new shader using your vertexShader, and fragmentShader.
Example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/d356uLg7/3/).

---

Also, based on @ngoKevin's anwser, adding more segments to the default plane will allow more vertices to move with the "wave" motion.

```
segments-height="20" segments-width="20"
```

fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/d356uLg7/5/).

**THREE**

To use a custom shader you need to use the [THREE.ShaderMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/ShaderMaterial):

```
THREE.ShaderMaterial({
     fragmentShader: this.fragmentShader, // custom fragment shader
     vertexShader: this.vertexShader, // custom vertex shader
     ......
```

It's a THREE material designed to be used with custom shaders.

Check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2jcfpx6b/).

Comment: I think the material is applied properly. The material component will overwrite the one defined in `waves`. If a mesh is present, it will write the material. Else it will wait for a mesh and then write the material.

Comment: Yeah, I think the solution is to provide the map uniform / texture value, else it will just display white. There's no material color.

Comment: @ngokevin I thought the "latter" component (waves) will overwrite both the material and the geometry components. Moreover shouldn't it be possibile to use either solution: 1) correct the shader, or 2) set up the material correctly on the waves component ? Anything but both at the same time ? :)

Comment: Only need to correct the shader. The order does not matter, the material component will apply either way.

Comment: @ngokevin i've updated my anwser, let me know if its more accurate.

Comment: Thank you so much guys. I am still unable to change the "y" position to create a wave effect. Here is my updated codepen https://codepen.io/nirajupadhyay11/pen/dgNBRJ?editors=1000.                                                   The example that I am trying to replicate is - https://codepen.io/gordonnl/pen/aBXpMd

Comment: Could you please help me with that? These shaders are a bit difficult to understand and debug given that console.log does not work

Comment: @piotradammilewski Just need to remove the pieces about the material overwriting (the first half of the answer).

Comment: @Niraj check out my update as well as Kevins anwser, the result should be satisfying

Comment: @ngokevin thought i removed them, was kinda late, updated once again, thanks :)

Comment: I cannot thank both of you enough!!! Really appreciate you taking time out and helping me

Answer (score 0):

You also need `segments-height="20" segments-width="20"` in your `a-plane` to give it vertices to displace. The default plane only has vertices on the corner so you won't get waves.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MPoBKz?editors=1000